# Multiple select on xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to select multiple nodes, but the `select` of the `xsl:for-each` method retrieve me only the first one..

Here is my code :

```
<div STYLE="height=100%;width=100%;overflow:visible;" id="VIEW1">
<table>
<tbody>
    <xsl:for-each select="//FUNCTION|PROPERTY[not(@toc) or @toc!='false']|CLASS|EVENT">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a> <xsl:attribute name="HREF">f_content.html#<xsl:value-of select="user:getId(.)"/></xsl:attribute>    <xsl:attribute name="TARGET">FRAMECONTENT</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The problem is situated here, it select only all of the `FUNCTION` nodes. :

```
<xsl:for-each select="//FUNCTION|PROPERTY[not(@toc) or @toc!='false']|CLASS|EVENT">
```

How can i change this line to retrieve all others node ?
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `//` or the relative paths for all nodes you need to select

```
<xsl:for-each select="//FUNCTION|//PROPERTY[not(@toc) or @toc!='false']|//CLASS|//EVENT">
```

Another approach is to use `self` axis, which will probably be more effective

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[self::FUNCTION|self::PROPERTY[not(@toc) or @toc!='false']|self::CLASS|self::EVENT]">
```

One more choice in case you are using XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:variable name="nodenames" select="'FUNCTION','CLASS','EVENT'"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//*[name()=$nodenames or self::PROPERTY[not(@toc) or @toc!='false']]">
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks you @Greenev